# What do I do if I've been asked to find the preimage of a vector, but the inverse of the Transformation Matrix doesn't exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix is:

cos(pi/3) 0

sin(pi/3) 0

I have no clue what to put. No solution?

Comment: The preimage is a set, not necessarily just a single vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the vector you're given is $(y_1,y_2)^\intercal$, try writing out the multiplication $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\pi/3} & 0 \\
\sin{\pi/3} & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{c}
y_1 \\
y_2 \end{array} \right)$$
and describe the set of vectors $(x_1,x_2)^\intercal$ which satisfy that criteria.

Comment: I found x1 and x2. Are you saying I now need to find them under T?

Comment: Or would x1 and x2 alone be a preimage?

Comment: When you multiply out the LHS you get two equations, $\cos{\pi/3}x_1=y_1$ and $\sin{\pi/3}x_1=y_2$.  These two equations only depend on $x_1$, so assuming a solution exists, the preimage will be the set of matrices with first entry as the value of $x_1$ given by those equations and any second entry you want (because it doesn't matter what $x_2$ you pick, it just gets multiplied by 0 anyway).